# Battery-powered FFT project

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, signal-processing, low-power, fft

I want to use FFT on a STM32F401C01CCU6. I chose this microcontroller because everyone says the F4 series is good at signal processing.

I want to make a project that will work with a battery; I am not going to charge it, so it needs to work at really really low currents.

I am going to use a MEMS microphone for getting data and then I am going to use FFT. Then my LoRa module will send the result to a LoRa receiver. The transmitter sends this data to the receiver every hour. Data will be really small, it will only send the time (for example: 3 minutes).

I want to count the time of signal at a certain frequency. For example, I want to count how long a 4 kHz signal arrives in a day but this needs to work for at least 1 year.

I will use sleep for the LoRa modules and it will be okay for power consumption but what about the FFT?

[image]

This is the STM32F401C datasheet. It says the microcontroller uses 23 mA for data processing. I can use a 3500 mAh battery for 6-7 days, which is a really short time. The MEMS microphone uses like a μA but data processing needs a lot.

How can I reduce these data processes so that the battery lasts for 1 year?

If I can't reduce it, can I do it with other microcontrollers?

Comment: How long does your FFT take?  (Perhaps you only run at 23mA for a very brief period).  Is it possible to do the processing at the receiver?

Comment: Also, for measuring the frequency you can use a method less greedy for power than FFT. For example, zero crossing detection

Comment: If you only need one (or a few) frequencies, the [Goertzel algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm) is probably a better bet than a full FFT.  You can tune the parameters so that you can get a specific response out of it.  You can trade the bandwidth of the detector to get a faster reaction time (wider bandwidth=faster reaction.)

Comment: Probably you can’t use it, but maybe you can. Vesper has a mic VM3011 which wakes the processor up at a sound level you can specify (not too precise, but it can use a bandwidth filter). 

I am currently investigating for my project a connection with ESP-S3 which can retrieve data by i2c with a ULP processor and wakes up if needed (after simple algorithm) the ESP32. Now I only use the regular ESP32. (Has a assembler language ulp, not my thing). You could count the exact wakeup time if success and add this to your measurement?

Comment: NB the datasheet: https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Vesper%20Tech/VM3011_DS.pdf

Comment: @jonathanjo, receiver can't do this because ı want to use multiple transmitter and 1 receiver. Also If I send it constantly, I will waste a lot of power. LoRa module Tx current approx. 100mA

Comment: @V.V.T thank you, I am gonna search it.

Comment: @JRE thank you, I am going to search it too. It says low-power but how much ? Is it like μA ?

Comment: @RemyHx thank you,  this method seems like really good but I can't full sleep MCU. I didn't mention but I need to use one more sensor with this project too. It needs  10 μA that's why I didn't mention. So I can't full sleep MCU.

Comment: Do you know about the Texas Instruments MSP430 low-power MCUs? The MSP430FR5994 has a hardware FFT. The processing power, SRAM size, etc is small compared to a STM32, but should be sufficient.

Comment: @Mattman944 thank you, I am going to check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to do a full FFT for this, a Goertzel filter should be sufficient. You don't need phase information either, which further reduces the effort required, and you probably don't need sample exact estimation of when tones begin and end, so you can subsample the filter output as well (it's a bandpass, but you can treat it like a lowpass from an aliasing point of view).

Comment: thank you, I couldn't find how much power it consume. Is it requires  μA level ?

Comment: @mrneedshelpalot, the filter will need a lot of multiplications, and that will take a bit of power while the CPU is running. Between bursts of activity, the CPU can go to a fairly low power state, but I doubt the end result will be in the µA range (also, check the power requirements for your LoRA transmitter -- these will be bursty as well, which means building a power supply that is efficient in a wide range.

Comment: @mrneedshelpalot You will probably need to actually write the software and **measure** the power consumption. Then, you can try different ways to decrease the power consumption, and you can see if it is low enough.

Comment: @mrneedshelpalot and if it's not low enough, maybe look at different microcontrollers. Someone told you this one was good for signal processing, but good doesn't always mean low-power. Maybe it meant high-speed.

Comment: @user253751 thank you for your comment. I am going to do that

Comment: @SimonRichter again thank you.